# How to add a record in a relation only if it doesn't already exist

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a groups model that I am adding users to using the `groups.members << user` syntax. I would like to do something like `find_or_create` on this but I am not sure if that is possible. Should I be using a unique clause. What is the best practice for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this is "best practice" but it's simple:

```
groups.members << user unless groups.members.where( :id => user.id )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
groups.members.where(field1: 'value', field2: 'another value').first_or_create
```

...with all the needed values in the `where` clause.